# Sending secure wordpress ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm making a page in Wordpress that every manager can manage their woo-commerce order.
There is a button that the manager can update the order status to completed.
I want to make a limit that only the related manager could change the status.

```
    <?php
            $nonce = wp_create_nonce( "manager_completed_nonce" );
            $link = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=manager_completed&order_id=' . $orderid . '&nonce=' . $nonce );
            echo '<a class="o-btn" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-order_id="' . $orderid . '" href="' . $link . '">Make it Completed</a>';
            ?>
```

and in function.php

```
    add_action( "wp_ajax_manager_completed", "manager_completed" );
    add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_manager_completed", "please_login" );


    function manager_completed() {

        // nonce check for an extra layer of security, the function will exit if it fails
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST[ 'nonce' ], "manager_completed_nonce" ) ) {
            exit( "Woof Woof Woof" );
        }
        $order = new WC_Order( $_REQUEST[ "order_id" ] );
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        die();
    }
    function please_login() {
        echo "You must log in";
        die();
    }
```

Now the security problem:
if a manager copies his own button URL and just changes the order id, he can change other managers' order status because he has a nonce code and it works for other order ids!!
How should I stop them?

Comment: do you have a manager_id on your order table?

Comment: @leli.1337 Yes I have a meta_key=manager and value=5 for example.

Comment: @leli.1337 I load orders by '$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
  'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
  'meta_key' => 'manager',
  'meta_value' => 5, //as an example
 );'

Comment: @leli.1337 Even if I check manager id, because it's appearing in the url, a manager with the id of 4 can change the id in the url and change another manager's order status.

Comment: Please check the solution i provided as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing the update_status you need to check the id of manager of the order.

You can check if the manager doing the update by getting id of the `WC_Order` and comparing it to the manager logged in.

Assuming that the manager id is the current user id the check before `update_status` should be like this. Be careful as you should not get manager id from URL as user might change it.

```
$managerId = get_current_user_id();
$ordeManagerId = get_post_meta( $_REQUEST[ "order_id" ], 'manager', true);
if($ordeManagerId != $managerId){
    exit( "Woof Woof Woof" );
}
```

Complete code should be like this:

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_manager_completed", "manager_completed" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_manager_completed", "please_login" );


function manager_completed() {

    // nonce check for an extra layer of security, the function will exit if it fails
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST[ 'nonce' ], "manager_completed_nonce" ) ) {
        exit( "Woof Woof Woof" );
    }
    $managerId = get_current_user_id();
    $ordeManagerId = get_post_meta( $_REQUEST[ "order_id" ], 'manager', true);
    if($ordeManagerId != $managerId){
        exit( "Woof Woof Woof" );
    }
    $order = new WC_Order( $_REQUEST[ "order_id" ] );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    die();
}
function please_login() {
    echo "You must log in";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Exactly! I got the idea. Thanks 